# Solve the given Functions for Complex numbers.(Complex Functions)

Tags: complex-analysis, functions, complex-numbers

[image]

I tried solving for the real solutions and found myself stuck. 
Here is how i tried to solve it:
 Re(z)=1

f2(M2)= f2(1+iy) {z=1+iy} i'm not so sure about this.

f2(m2)= (1+iy)^2  {as z^2 is f2}

further solving i get y^2=4x-4 and can't move further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $f_2$, the image of $M_2$ is
$$\{z^2\mid Re(z)=1\}=\{(x+iy)^2\mid x=1\}\ .$$
If you write $z^2=u+iv$ then doing the algebra gives
$$u=1-y^2\ ,\quad v=2y\ .$$
You can recognise this as the parametric description of a ceratin curve, or you can eliminate the parameter to get
$$4u=4-v^2\ .$$
This is the equation in the $(u,v)$ plane of a familiar curve.

---

You can do $f_1$ in the same way, in fact it will be a bit easier.

Comment: thanks for pointing that out. There was a Typo there. I hope you can check through that once again. and thanks !

Comment: You can now do $f_1$ in the same way as $f_2$, in fact it will be a bit easier.

Comment: Awesome man thnaks a ton!!